# Can't make the response cached in browser

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

In my controller action before the response return line I have the following code:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(true);
```

When i call this action like "/Controller/Action" then the result is cached well in browser. But when I try to add any parameter like here "/Controller/Action?v=1" then it's never cached more (tried in fiddler). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute on your controller action. You can change where the cache can happen with the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) parameter.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 6000, VaryByParam = "v", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
public ActionResult MyAction(int? v) {
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Won't it make the response cached in .NET server, not in client browser?

Comment: added "?v=4" to the end of the request, and it called server code each time i run it :(

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? Because that impacts caching.